# Advantages & Benefits - 利益 vs 优势 vs 好处

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to work out the difference between 利益, 优势 and 好处. They all seem to be nouns and relate to having an advantage, but I can't find any resources which outline when you would use word in preference to another.

If anyone is able to provide some insight into this, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

利益 benefits/ interest (mainly of monetary or material gain)

优势 advantage

好处 benefits (general term for benefits, e.g improve health, avoid criticism and of course, monetary gain)

利益 is more literary and 好处 is more colloquial

Example sentences:

军事优势 = military advantage

国家利益 = national interest

获取利益 = gain benefits

在美国留学的好处 = Benefits of studying in the United States

Comment: Thanks Tang Ho - that makes it really clear!